# How to get Julia Makie Output in python Jupiter notebook?

Tags: python, julia, jupyter, makie.jl

Running the following notebook cells

```
%load_ext julia.magic
```

```
%%julia
using GLMakie 

function plot_something()
    odeSol(x,y) = Point(-x, 2y)             # x'(t) = -x, y'(t) = 2y
    fig = Figure(resolution =(400,400))
    ax = Axis(fig)
    streamplot!(ax, odeSol, -2..2, -2..2, colormap = :plasma, 
        gridsize= (32,32), arrow_size = 0.07)
    fig[1,1] = ax
    fig
end
```

```
from julia import Main
Main.show_something()
```

yields `<PyCall.jlwrap Scene (400px, 400px):'
rather than the hoped for figure. Any good fixes?

Answer (score 0):

A possible fix for now

```
function makie2image(fig)
    buf = IOBuffer()
    Makie.backend_show(GLMakie.GLBackend(), buf, MIME("image/png"), fig.scene)
    pyimport("IPython").display.Image(pybytes(buf.data))
end
```

Used as:

```
Main.makie2image(Main.plot_something())
```

Comment: thank you. That works! Does "for now" mean this might be addressed by Makie devs in the future?

Comment: @ea42_gh I just meant until someone finds a more elegant solution. There's no problem with Makie specifically - I think it's the pyjulia interop that is lacking a bit here.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer did not work for me. Instead I had to use the newer [JuliaCall](https://github.com/JuliaPy/PythonCall.jl) library

```py
from juliacall import Main as jl

# Install the Makie package. This only needs to be run once then Main reloaded
import juliapkg
juliapkg.add("GLMakie", uuid="e9467ef8-e4e7-5192-8a1a-b1aee30e663a")

# Import GLMAkie into the Julia session
jl.seval("using GLMakie")

import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0.1, 10, 30)
f = lambda x: x**2 * np.sin(x + 1/x)
y = f(x)

fig, ax, lns = jl.lines(x, y, label="Simple function")
jl.axislegend(position=jl.seval(':lt'))
fig
```

Unfortunately this loses the cool `%%julia` cell magic